# Are there any nuance differences between the syntax this->func() and func()?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

If I have a class with a virtual function and no free functions, are there any differences between `this->func()` and `func()`

```
class Base {
    virtual void A() { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; };
    void B() { this->A(); };
    void C() { A(); };
};

class Derived : public Base {
    virtual void A() { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; };
    void B2() { this->A(); };
    void C2() { A(); };
};
```

Are there any differences in the execution of methods `B()` and `C()`? What about the methods `B2()` and `C2()`?

Comment: Entirely stylistic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the example you've posted, there is no difference between the two syntaxes. They're completely identical.

There are two cases where there is a difference. One is if you have a template class that inherits from a type that depends on a template argument. For example:

```
template <typename T> class Base {
public:
    void doSomething() const {
       std::cout << "Do ALL the things!" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T> class Derived: public Base<T> {
public:
    void doSomethingElse() const {
        doSomething();       // Error!
        this->doSomething(); // Okay
    }
};
```

Here, since `Derived<T>` inherits from the type `Base<T>`, which depends on a template argument, name lookup is done in a two-step process. If you call `doSomething` using the unqualified syntax, then the compiler doesn't know to look into `Base<T>` to find it and will report an error. However, if you say `this->doSomething()`, it knows that you're calling a member function and will eventually figure out that it's supposed to look in `Base<T>`.

The other case arises if you have a local object declared inside the function whose name is the same as a member function. For example:

```
class ThisIsSillyDontDoThisLikeSeriouslyDont {
public:
    void doSomething() const {
        std::cout << "Do ALL the things!" << std::endl;
    }

    void weirdFunction() const {
        auto doSomething = [] {
            std::cout << "I'm afraid there's nothing to be done" << std::endl;
        };

        doSomething();       // Calls the local function
        this->doSomething(); // Calls the member function
    }
};
```

This second case is so rare that I've never seen it, and I'd go so far as to say that it's really poor coding style.

Aside from these rare cases, though, there's no difference between calling a member function on yourself with and without `this->` as a prefix.

Comment: There is another case in which they are different: If a locally declared funct{ion|or} (it would be named `doSomething` in this case) in the `doSomethingElse` would shadow the method with the same name.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You're absolutely right. Let me go update this.

Answer (score 3):

Generally there is no difference, since the standard requires a call to a member function in the form `A()` to be equivalent to `(*this).A()`. Some examples where there are a difference are:

1. If there is a block-scope declaration of `A`, then `A()` will call the function declared, whereas `this->A()` will always call the member function. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea49916562bd4371
2. If `A` is a member of a dependent base class then an attempt to call it as `A()` will fail; `this->A()` is required to postpone the name lookup until instantiation time.

Answer (score 0):

Cppreference concerning [Non-static member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions) states that there is a difference in the context of template definitions:

> Within the body of a non-static member function of X, any
>   id-expression E (e.g. an identifier) that resolves to a non-type
>   non-static member of X or of a base class of X, is transformed to a
>   member access expression (*this).E (unless it's already a part of a
>   member access expression). This does not occur in template definition
>   context, so a name may have to be prefixed with this-> explicitly to
>   become dependent.

So in your example it does not make a difference, but in other contexts, e.g. when defining templates, it may.